# how to access variables with varying names?

Tags: python, variables

How can I use a for loop to increment variable names with numbers in python 3.2?
p is player and can be 1 or 2.  p1 and p2 are the different symbols for each player.

```
    p = 1
    p1 = x
    p2 = i
    for c in range(1,3):
        input('Player {} ({}), ...? '.format(p,(locals()['p'+str(p)])))
```

This locals() function is making a dictionary but I want that to be the variable name. How?

Comment: There probably should not ever be a need to do this. What kind of program are you trying to write, exactly?

Comment: What is the end goal you're trying to accomplish? As Anorov mentioned, this isn't likely to be a good approach.

Comment: To explain why this isn't likely to be a good approach: What you're doing now actually works just fine. The problem is, presumably, that you're trying to use it from a different scope, where the variables aren't in `locals()`. To deal with that, you have to pass the `locals` dictionary around. At which point, you might as well be maintaining a normal dictionary and passing that around instead of trying to access local variables by name. There are a few good exceptions to this rule, but if one of them is relevant, you should explain it right off the bat, or all of your answers will be "Why?!"

Answer (score 2):

Data is stored in data structures, not variable names. Use a dict, list or any other data structure.

```
players = []

for c in range(1,3):
        pl = input('Player P{} ...? '.format(c)
        players.append(pl)

print players[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple class to hold players.  Here's an example that lets you request players either literally, or passing a variable number.

```
class Players:
    def __init__(self, players):
        self.__dict__ = {"p{}".format(i+1):p for i,p in enumerate(players)}
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.__dict__["p{}".format(item)]

p = Players(["player 1 obj", "player 2 obj"])

# equivalent 
print p.p2
print p[2]
```